# No routes match to action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I'm doing a shopping cart with the gem:  gem act_as_shopping_cart (https://github.com/crowdint/acts_as_shopping_cart)

This gem do not have a good documentation, butis popular.

in my action add_item I'm getting the error:

No route matches {:action=>"add_item", :id=>nil, :controller=>"comprar"}

This is my controller to items:

clas

```
s ComprarController < SuperSiteController
  def index
    @v = Video.order('created_at asc')
    @n = News.all
    @cat = Category.all
  end

  def show
    @v = Video.find(params[:id])
    @n = News.all
    @cat = Category.all
    @cart = Cart.new
  end

  def add_item
    @cart = Cart.create
    @product = Video.find(params[:id])

    @cart.add(@product, @product.week_price)
  end

end
```

the model to my cart:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :id, :owner_id, :owner_type, :quantity,
              :item_id, :item_type, :price


    acts_as_shopping_cart_using :video
  end
```

the model to items to sell:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :active, :desc, :embed, :img1, :img1_uid, 
            :img2, :img2_uid, :img3, :img3_uid, :img4, 
            :img4_uid, :infos, :month_price, :slug, :title, 
            :trailer, :views, :week_price, :year_price, :category_id



    belongs_to :category

  acts_as_shopping_cart_item_for :cart

end
```

and the code in my view "show":

```
<% form_for @cart, :url => {:action => "add_item", :id => @cart.id} do |f| %>
       <%= f.submit 'Add to Cart' %>
<% end %>
```

Someone is seeing something that I'm not?

I following the documentation, but still get this error

> **Add Items**
>
> To add an item to the cart you use the add method. You have to send
>   the object and the price of the object as parameters.
>
> So, if you had a Product class, you would do something like this:

```
@cart = Cart.create
@product = Product.find(1)

@cart.add(@product, 99.99)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `config/routes.rb` please. Also, you can't use `@cart.id` in your new method to create the route for a form, as `@cart` is not persisted yet and has no id.

Comment: ...or `rake routes` to see your routes please

Answer (score 1):

in your `config/routes.rb`

you should add

```
post "comprar/add_item"
```

you should also check your routes to make sure you have all the Comprar routes `rake routes`

Answer (score 1):

In your `config/routes.rb` file you need to have:

```
resources :comprars do
  collection do
     post 'add_item'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

--

**Routes**

> No route matches {:action=>"add_item", :id=>nil,
>   :controller=>"comprar"}

The reason for this is that your Rails `route` structure depends on having an `:id` for your `add_item` action. This is what's known as a [`member`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) route, meaning that it expects a *single* entry.

The difference between `member` and `collection` routes is that a *collection* will retrieve a large number of items from the `Model` (hence no requirement for an `id`), whereas a `member` will only pull a single item (requiring the `id`)

Your routes at the moment require an `id` for the `item` of your cart, and you're not passing it, hence the "no routes" error.

The way to fix this is to include the `id` in your route / `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to "Add To Cart", add_item_path(item.id), method: :post %>
```

--

**Form**

I know you want to use a form. For this, I'd probably use the [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) helper, as defined here:

```
<%= button_to "Add To Cart", add_item_path(item.id) %>
```

This will request the correct route whilst maintaining the "form" functionality you've wanted to implement

Answer (score 0):

You are using @cart.id in your form which is not present at the time of submit. And also you are using this ID to find video add_item action. So you should use particular video id(@video.id or something similar) in your form.

Also you do have some problem in your routes file. try run "rake routes". you should have route "comprar/:id/add_item" in result. If not there add this route to your route file will solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem lies with your controllers.

```
ComprarController < SuperSiteController
```

should be

```
ComprarsController < SuperSiteController
```

In Rails, controller names must be plural, this is a convention.

Fix that line, and change the name of your file from

```
comprarcontroller.rb
```

to

```
comprarscontroller.rb
```

And that should fix your problem